# The ListS3 processor is not working with nested folders

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a delta table inside S3:
[image]

I'm trying to list all the files using the ListS3 processor with the `Tracking Entities` strategy:
[image]

The issue is that the processor does **not** list all the files from the last 7 days when it is run. It seems to only takes files from the `_delta_log` folder, ignoring others. Same thing when new folders are created the following days. After a few days the processor has listed this:
[image]

It ignores the folders created each day with `import_date=<date>`.

I have tried changing the `Tracking Time Window` with no effect. Using the `Tracking Timestamps` strategy seems to solve the issue at first but reading the doc I see that its simple cache can miss files with nested folders. That why I was trying to use `Tracking Entities` in the first place...

I have also looked at the source code for the ListS3 processor for bugs, to no avail.
Did anybody successfully used the ListS3 processor with a folder structure ?